# Locus of all points

Tags: spherical-trigonometry, spin-geometry

What is the locus of all points equidistant from a fixed point and a fixed circle on a sphere? (By examining an "extreme" case, i.e. the fixed point being the North Pole and the fixed circle being a Great Circle that ALMOST passes through the North Pole, it is obvious to me that the locus can not be a circle. But I can't find the problem dealt with on this or any other site.)

Comment: How do you define your distance? Is it the Euclidian one, or the distance on the sphere?

Comment: Thank you @Andrei. I should have specified "spherical" distance i.e. the angular sweep of the (usually unique) connecting Great Circle. Bearing this in mind  I think answerrer correctly answerred the question, not for "spherical distance, but for (the square) of Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let choose the spherical coordinate system in such a way that center of the circle lies on the polar axis. Then the circle represents a circle of latitude with polar angle $\theta_c$. Let $\theta_p$ be the polar angle of the fixed point, its azimuthal angle $\phi_p$ being $0$. Then the locus of points in question (with distance being assumed spherical) is determined by the equation:
$$L(\theta,\phi)=0$$
with
$$
L(\theta,\phi)=\sin\theta_p\sin\theta\cos\phi+\cos\theta_p\cos\theta-\cos(\theta-\theta_c).
$$

Comment: Yeah, there was something wrong with my brain stemming from the fact that I asked my question incorrectly...

Comment: @jstark What exactly was wrong with the question? I have assumed the distance to be spherical (i.e. "the angular sweep of the ... connecting Great Circle"), and this seems to be precisely your intention.

Comment: Yes @user, you answered the original question correctly and I (tried to) "accept" it. But it wasn't the question I wanted to ask which was "What is the locus of all midpoints of Great Circular "segments" extending from a fixed point to the various points on a (possibly Not Great) circle on a sphere?" Your solution is sort of the analogue of a parabola (on a sphere with the fixed circle acting as "directrix") Had you used "angular sweep" and alterred the ratio" of the distances (from unity) we would have had analogues of the hyperbola and elipse. But I wanted the analogue of a 1800,s "linkage".

Comment: @jstark Ok, I see what you mean.